# MySQL left outer join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables,

first table structure (data) :

```
-id
-name
-title
-mail
-source_id
```

and second table ( mail ) :

```
-id
-record_id
-mail
-date
```

there may be some duplicate records in data table and some records with empty mail field.
im sending emails to these clients and i want to save whos email has been sent with time in mail table.
and i want to exclude records which their emails has been already sent

i use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `data`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `mail`
ON `data`.`source_id` != `mail`.`record_id`
WHERE `data`.`mail` != ''
ORDER BY `data`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

also i tried :

```
SELECT * FROM `data`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `mail`
USING(`mail`)
WHERE `data`.`mail` != ''
ORDER BY `data`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

but it still shows duplicate records and dont exclude records from mail table

any ideas ? or better solution ? btw i cant alter first table and add a new field for checking sent emails

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

let's change `!=` to `IS NOT NULL` (I also think you should use `<>` instead of `!=`)

```
SELECT * FROM `data`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `mail`
ON `data`.`source_id` != `mail`.`record_id`
WHERE `data`.`mail` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `data`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

UPDATE: let's try DISTINCT

```
SELECT (DISTINCT data.email) FROM `data`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `mail`
ON `data`.`source_id` != `mail`.`record_id`
WHERE `data`.`mail` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `data`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but problem is not filtering empty `data`.`mail`, your code works fine in filtering, but it still shows duplicate content and dont exclude mail table records from dataset